# How to mutate all value of a field in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, export-to-csv

I created a script to export Elasticsearch data to a csv file by using Logstash and its plugin. I want to mutate the value of a field. For example, I exported a field `company` and the value of this field are: `google, amazon...` I need to add a string `company-` before these values on the csv file like: `company-google, company-amazon`. I checked the `Mutate filter plugin` of Logstash but I don't find any function to solve this problem.Is it possible to mutate these values with Logstash and export to csv file?

```
 input {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "give_index_name"
    query => '
    {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        }   
    } 
  '
  }
}
output {
  csv {
    # elastic field name
    fields => ["company", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"]
    # This is path where we store output.   
    path => "/scrape/csv-export.csv"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `mutate` filter.

First you would need to create a temporary new field that will concatenate the string `company-` with the value of the field `company`.

You would do that with the following `mutate` filter.

```
mutate {
    add_field => {"[@metadata][company]" => "company-%{company}" }
    remove_field => ["company"]
}
```

This will create a field named `@metadata.company` with the value `company-CompanyName`, eg. `company-anything`, then it will remove the `company` field.

Next you will need to add again a field named company with the value of the `@metadata.company` field.

This is done using the following `mutate`:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "company" => "%{[@metadata][company]}" }
}
```

This way you will have the value `company-anything` in the field `company`.

There is no need to remove the `@metadata.company` field as the `@metadata` object will not be part of the output message.